# FFmpeg stdout emits more frames than it should

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg, rxjs

I am running this command to get two images per second from an rtsp stream:

```js
const ffmpeg = spawn(this.ffmpeg, [
      // Set the frame rate of the input video to 2 frames per second
      '-r',
      '2',
      // Specify that the RTSP stream should use TCP as the transport protocol
      '-rtsp_transport',
      'tcp',
      // Set the input source to the RTSP stream specified by the `rtspUrl` variable
      '-i',
      rtspUrl,
      // Set the video filter to only output two frames per second (final video)
      '-vf',
      'fps=2',
      // Set the output format to "image2pipe," which specifies that the output should be written to stdout as a series of images in a pipe
      '-f',
      'image2pipe',
      // Overwrite any existing output file without prompting for confirmation
      '-y',
      // Set the output destination to stdout
      '-',
    ]);
```

I am subscribing to the stdout and saving each emit into a file (just for testing, I need to process the data later)

```js
    let i = 0;
    from(ffmpeg.stdout)
      .pipe(
        concatMap((data) => {
          i++
          return writeFile(`file_${i}`, data).then(() => i);
        }),
      )
      .subscribe((i) => {
        this.imageLogger.log(`file_${i} saved`);
      });
```

The thing is, I am getting a lot more than 2 images per second:

```
i       | [Nest] 431  - 12/28/2022, 1:16:09 PM     LOG [Image Logger] stderr: ffmpeg version 5.0.1-static https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/  Copyright (c) 2000-2022 the FFmpeg developers
api       |   built with gcc 8 (Debian 8.3.0-6)
api       |   configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-debug --disable-ffplay --disable-indev=sndio --disable-outdev=sndio --cc=gcc --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-gmp --enable-libgme --enable-gray --enable-libaom --enable-libfribidi --enable-libass --enable-libvmaf --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-librubberband --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libsrt --enable-libvorbis --enable-libopus --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libdav1d --enable-libxvid --enable-libzvbi --enable-libzimg
api       |   libavutil      57. 17.100 / 57. 17.100
api       |   libavcodec     59. 18.100 / 59. 18.100
api       |   libavformat    59. 16.100 / 59. 16.100
api       |   libavdevice    59.  4.100 / 59.  4.100
api       |   libavfilter     8. 24.100 /  8. 24.100
api       |   libswscale      6.  4.100 /  6.  4.100
api       |   libswresample   4.  3.100 /  4.  3.100
api       |   libpostproc    56.  3.100 / 56.  3.100
api       |   configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-debug --disable-ffplay --disable-indev=sndio --disable-outdev=sndio --cc=gcc --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-gmp --enable-libgme --enable-gray --enable-libaom --enable-libfribidi --enable-libass --enable-libvmaf --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-librubberband --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libsrt --enable-libvorbis --enable-libopus --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libdav1d --enable-libxvid --enable-libzvbi --enable-libzimg
api       |   libavutil      57. 17.100 / 57. 17.100
api       |   libavcodec     59. 18.100 / 59. 18.100
api       |   libavformat    59. 16.100 / 59. 16.100
api       |   libavdevice    59.  4.100 / 59.  4.100
api       |   libavfilter     8. 24.100 /  8. 24.100
api       |   libswscale      6.  4.100 /  6.  4.100
api       |   libswresample   4.  3.100 /  4.  3.100
api       |   libpostproc    56.  3.100 / 56.  3.100
api       | [Nest] 431  - 12/28/2022, 1:16:12 PM     LOG [Image Logger] stderr: Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #0.1 : mono
api       | Input #0, rtsp, from 'rtsp://user:password@192.68.45.54:554/stream2':
api       |   Metadata:
api       |     title           : Session streamed by "TP-LINK RTSP Server"
api       |     comment         : stream2
api       |   Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
api       |   Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (High), yuvj420p(pc, bt709, progressive), 640x360, 15 fps, 28.58 tbr, 90k tbn
api       |   Stream #0:1: Audio: pcm_alaw, 8000 Hz, mono, s16, 64 kb/s
api       |
api       | [Nest] 431  - 12/28/2022, 1:16:12 PM     LOG [Image Logger] stderr: Stream mapping:
api       |   Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> mjpeg (native))
api       | Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
api       |
api       | [Nest] 431  - 12/28/2022, 1:16:12 PM     LOG [Image Logger] stderr: Output #0, image2pipe, to 'pipe:':
api       |   Metadata:
api       |     title           : Session streamed by "TP-LINK RTSP Server"
api       |     comment         : stream2
api       |     encoder         : Lavf59.16.100
api       |   Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj420p(pc, bt709, progressive), 640x360, q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 2 fps, 2 tbn
api       |
api       | [Nest] 431  - 12/28/2022, 1:16:12 PM     LOG [Image Logger] stderr:     Metadata:
api       |       encoder         : Lavc59.18.100 mjpeg
api       |     Side data:
api       |       cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/200000 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: N/A
api       | [Nest] 431  - 12/28/2022, 1:16:12 PM     LOG [Image Logger] stderr: frame=    1 fps=0.0 q=5.0 size=      23kB time=00:00:00.50 bitrate= 383.9kbits/s speed=59.4x
api       | [Nest] 431  - 12/28/2022, 1:16:12 PM     LOG [Image Logger] file_1.jpg saved
api       | [Nest] 431  - 12/28/2022, 1:16:12 PM     LOG [Image Logger] file_2.jpg saved
api       | [Nest] 431  - 12/28/2022, 1:16:12 PM     LOG [Image Logger] file_3.jpg saved
api       | [Nest] 431  - 12/28/2022, 1:16:12 PM     LOG [Image Logger] file_4.jpg saved
api       | [Nest] 431  - 12/28/2022, 1:16:12 PM     LOG [Image Logger] file_5.jpg saved
api       | [Nest] 431  - 12/28/2022, 1:16:12 PM     LOG [Image Logger] file_6.jpg saved
api       | [Nest] 431  - 12/28/2022, 1:16:12 PM     LOG [Image Logger] file_7.jpg saved
api       | [Nest] 431  - 12/28/2022, 1:16:12 PM     LOG [Image Logger] file_8.jpg saved
api       | [Nest] 431  - 12/28/2022, 1:16:12 PM     LOG [Image Logger] file_9.jpg saved
api       | [Nest] 431  - 12/28/2022, 1:16:12 PM     LOG [Image Logger] file_10.jpg saved
api       | [Nest] 431  - 12/28/2022, 1:16:12 PM     LOG [Image Logger] file_11.jpg saved
api       | [Nest] 431  - 12/28/2022, 1:16:12 PM     LOG [Image Logger] file_12.jpg saved
api       | [Nest] 431  - 12/28/2022, 1:16:12 PM     LOG [Image Logger] file_13.jpg saved
api       | [Nest] 431  - 12/28/2022, 1:16:12 PM     LOG [Image Logger] file_14.jpg saved
api       | [Nest] 431  - 12/28/2022, 1:16:12 PM     LOG [Image Logger] file_15.jpg saved
api       | [Nest] 431  - 12/28/2022, 1:16:12 PM     LOG [Image Logger] file_16.jpg saved
api       | [Nest] 431  - 12/28/2022, 1:16:12 PM     LOG [Image Logger] file_17.jpg saved
api       | [Nest] 431  - 12/28/2022, 1:16:12 PM     LOG [Image Logger] file_18.jpg saved
api       | [Nest] 431  - 12/28/2022, 1:16:12 PM     LOG [Image Logger] file_19.jpg saved
api       | [Nest] 431  - 12/28/2022, 1:16:12 PM     LOG [Image Logger] file_20.jpg saved
api       | [Nest] 431  - 12/28/2022, 1:16:12 PM     LOG [Image Logger] file_21.jpg saved
api       | [Nest] 431  - 12/28/2022, 1:16:12 PM     LOG [Image Logger] file_22.jpg saved
api       | [Nest] 431  - 12/28/2022, 1:16:12 PM     LOG [Image Logger] file_23.jpg saved
api       | [Nest] 431  - 12/28/2022, 1:16:12 PM     LOG [Image Logger] file_24.jpg saved
api       | [Nest] 431  - 12/28/2022, 1:16:12 PM     LOG [Image Logger] file_25.jpg saved
api       | [Nest] 431  - 12/28/2022, 1:16:12 PM     LOG [Image Logger] file_26.jpg saved
api       | [Nest] 431  - 12/28/2022, 1:16:12 PM     LOG [Image Logger] stderr: frame=   27 fps=0.0 q=16.0 size=     559kB time=00:00:13.50 bitrate= 339.3kbits/s speed=25.3x
api       | [Nest] 431  - 12/28/2022, 1:16:12 PM     LOG [Image Logger] file_27.jpg saved
api       | [Nest] 431  - 12/28/2022, 1:16:12 PM     LOG [Image Logger] file_28.jpg saved
api       | [Nest] 431  - 12/28/2022, 1:16:12 PM     LOG [Image Logger] file_29.jpg saved
api       | [Nest] 431  - 12/28/2022, 1:16:12 PM     LOG [Image Logger] file_30.jpg saved
api       | [Nest] 431  - 12/28/2022, 1:16:12 PM     LOG [Image Logger] file_31.jpg saved
api       | [Nest] 431  - 12/28/2022, 1:16:12 PM     LOG [Image Logger] file_32.jpg saved
api       | [Nest] 431  - 12/28/2022, 1:16:13 PM     LOG [Image Logger] file_33.jpg saved
api       | [Nest] 431  - 12/28/2022, 1:16:13 PM     LOG [Image Logger] stderr: frame=   34 fps= 33 q=16.6 size=     632kB time=00:00:17.00 bitrate= 304.6kbits/s speed=16.3x
api       | [Nest] 431  - 12/28/2022, 1:16:13 PM     LOG [Image Logger] file_34.jpg saved
api       | [Nest] 431  - 12/28/2022, 1:16:13 PM     LOG [Image Logger] file_35.jpg saved
api       | [Nest] 431  - 12/28/2022, 1:16:13 PM     LOG [Image Logger] file_36.jpg saved
api       | [Nest] 431  - 12/28/2022, 1:16:13 PM     LOG [Image Logger] file_37.jpg saved
api       | [Nest] 431  - 12/28/2022, 1:16:13 PM     LOG [Image Logger] file_38.jpg saved
api       | [Nest] 431  - 12/28/2022, 1:16:13 PM     LOG [Image Logger] file_39.jpg saved
api       | [Nest] 431  - 12/28/2022, 1:16:13 PM     LOG [Image Logger] file_40.jpg saved
api       | [Nest] 431  - 12/28/2022, 1:16:13 PM     LOG [Image Logger] file_41.jpg saved
api       | [Nest] 431  - 12/28/2022, 1:16:13 PM     LOG [Image Logger] stderr: frame=   41 fps= 26 q=16.5 size=     705kB time=00:00:20.50 bitrate= 281.7kbits/s speed=13.2x
api       | [Nest] 431  - 12/28/2022, 1:16:13 PM     LOG [Image Logger] file_42.jpg saved
api       | [Nest] 431  - 12/28/2022, 1:16:13 PM     LOG [Image Logger] file_43.jpg saved
api       | [Nest] 431  - 12/28/2022, 1:16:13 PM     LOG [Image Logger] file_44.jpg saved
api       | [Nest] 431  - 12/28/2022, 1:16:13 PM     LOG [Image Logger] file_45.jpg saved
api       | [Nest] 431  - 12/28/2022, 1:16:13 PM     LOG [Image Logger] file_46.jpg saved
api       | [Nest] 431  - 12/28/2022, 1:16:14 PM     LOG [Image Logger] file_47.jpg saved
api       | [Nest] 431  - 12/28/2022, 1:16:14 PM     LOG [Image Logger] file_48.jpg saved
api       | [Nest] 431  - 12/28/2022, 1:16:14 PM     LOG [Image Logger] stderr: frame=   48 fps= 23 q=16.4 size=     779kB time=00:00:24.00 bitrate= 265.9kbits/s speed=11.6x
api       | [Nest] 431  - 12/28/2022, 1:16:14 PM     LOG [Image Logger] file_49.jpg saved
api       | [Nest] 431  - 12/28/2022, 1:16:14 PM     LOG [Image Logger] file_50.jpg saved
api       | [Nest] 431  - 12/28/2022, 1:16:14 PM     LOG [Image Logger] file_51.jpg saved
api       | [Nest] 431  - 12/28/2022, 1:16:14 PM     LOG [Image Logger] file_52.jpg saved
api       | [Nest] 431  - 12/28/2022, 1:16:14 PM     LOG [Image Logger] file_53.jpg saved
api       | [Nest] 431  - 12/28/2022, 1:16:14 PM     LOG [Image Logger] file_54.jpg saved
api       | [Nest] 431  - 12/28/2022, 1:16:14 PM     LOG [Image Logger] file_55.jpg saved
api       | [Nest] 431  - 12/28/2022, 1:16:14 PM     LOG [Image Logger] stderr: frame=   56 fps= 22 q=16.1 size=     865kB time=00:00:28.00 bitrate= 253.0kbits/s speed=10.9x
api       | [Nest] 431  - 12/28/2022, 1:16:14 PM     LOG [Image Logger] file_56.jpg saved
api       | [Nest] 431  - 12/28/2022, 1:16:14 PM     LOG [Image Logger] file_57.jpg saved
api       | [Nest] 431  - 12/28/2022, 1:16:14 PM     LOG [Image Logger] file_58.jpg saved
api       | [Nest] 431  - 12/28/2022, 1:16:14 PM     LOG [Image Logger] file_59.jpg saved
api       | [Nest] 431  - 12/28/2022, 1:16:14 PM     LOG [Image Logger] file_60.jpg saved
api       | [Nest] 431  - 12/28/2022, 1:16:15 PM     LOG [Image Logger] file_61.jpg saved
api       | [Nest] 431  - 12/28/2022, 1:16:15 PM     LOG [Image Logger] file_62.jpg saved
api       | [Nest] 431  - 12/28/2022, 1:16:15 PM     LOG [Image Logger] file_63.jpg saved
api       | [Nest] 431  - 12/28/2022, 1:16:15 PM     LOG [Image Logger] stderr: frame=   63 fps= 20 q=15.5 size=     939kB time=00:00:31.50 bitrate= 244.3kbits/s speed=10.2x
api       | [Nest] 431  - 12/28/2022, 1:16:15 PM     LOG [Image Logger] file_64.jpg saved
api       | [Nest] 431  - 12/28/2022, 1:16:15 PM     LOG [Image Logger] file_65.jpg saved
api       | [Nest] 431  - 12/28/2022, 1:16:15 PM     LOG [Image Logger] file_66.jpg saved
api       | [Nest] 431  - 12/28/2022, 1:16:15 PM     LOG [Image Logger] file_67.jpg saved
api       | [Nest] 431  - 12/28/2022, 1:16:15 PM     LOG [Image Logger] file_68.jpg saved
api       | [Nest] 431  - 12/28/2022, 1:16:15 PM     LOG [Image Logger] file_69.jpg saved
api       | [Nest] 431  - 12/28/2022, 1:16:15 PM     LOG [Image Logger] file_70.jpg saved
api       | [Nest] 431  - 12/28/2022, 1:16:15 PM     LOG [Image Logger] stderr: frame=   70 fps= 19 q=15.4 size=    1017kB time=00:00:35.00 bitrate= 238.0kbits/s speed= 9.7x
api       | [Nest] 431  - 12/28/2022, 1:16:15 PM     LOG [Image Logger] file_71.jpg saved
api       | [Nest] 431  - 12/28/2022, 1:16:15 PM     LOG [Image Logger] file_72.jpg saved
api       | [Nest] 431  - 12/28/2022, 1:16:15 PM     LOG [Image Logger] file_73.jpg saved
api       | [Nest] 431  - 12/28/2022, 1:16:15 PM     LOG [Image Logger] file_74.jpg saved
api       | [Nest] 431  - 12/28/2022, 1:16:15 PM     LOG [Image Logger] file_75.jpg saved
api       | [Nest] 431  - 12/28/2022, 1:16:16 PM     LOG [Image Logger] file_76.jpg saved
api       | [Nest] 431  - 12/28/2022, 1:16:16 PM     LOG [Image Logger] file_77.jpg saved
api       | [Nest] 431  - 12/28/2022, 1:16:16 PM     LOG [Image Logger] stderr: frame=   78 fps= 19 q=15.1 size=    1106kB time=00:00:39.00 bitrate= 232.4kbits/s speed=9.48x
api       | [Nest] 431  - 12/28/2022, 1:16:16 PM     LOG [Image Logger] file_78.jpg saved
api       | [Nest] 431  - 12/28/2022, 1:16:16 PM     LOG [Image Logger] file_79.jpg saved
api       | [Nest] 431  - 12/28/2022, 1:16:16 PM     LOG [Image Logger] file_80.jpg saved
api       | [Nest] 431  - 12/28/2022, 1:16:16 PM     LOG [Image Logger] file_81.jpg saved
api       | [Nest] 431  - 12/28/2022, 1:16:16 PM     LOG [Image Logger] file_82.jpg saved
```

Am I missing some part? why I do not only get 2 stdout events pro second?

## Edit:

ffmpeg version 5.0.1-static
node: 18.12.1

## Edit 2:

When I run this command on the terminal:

```
ffmpeg -r 2 -rtsp_transport tcp -i "rtsp://user:password@192.68.45.54:554/stream2" -vf fps=2 -timecode 00:00:00:00 test.mp4
```

The generated video has a frame rate of 2 but it looks like it is in slow motion. Since the source video has also a timer, I see how it takes something like 12 "frames" to go from one second to another.

This is the output:

```
fmpeg version 5.1.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2022 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple clang version 14.0.0 (clang-1400.0.29.202)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/5.1.2_1 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-ffplay --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-libaom --enable-libbluray --enable-libdav1d --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-librav1e --enable-librist --enable-librubberband --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsrt --enable-libtesseract --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-frei0r --enable-libass --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libspeex --enable-libsoxr --enable-libzmq --enable-libzimg --disable-libjack --disable-indev=jack --enable-videotoolbox
  libavutil      57. 28.100 / 57. 28.100
  libavcodec     59. 37.100 / 59. 37.100
  libavformat    59. 27.100 / 59. 27.100
  libavdevice    59.  7.100 / 59.  7.100
  libavfilter     8. 44.100 /  8. 44.100
  libswscale      6.  7.100 /  6.  7.100
  libswresample   4.  7.100 /  4.  7.100
  libpostproc    56.  6.100 / 56.  6.100
Input #0, rtsp, from 'rtsp://user:password@192.68.45.54:554/stream2':
  Metadata:
    title           : Session streamed by "TP-LINK RTSP Server"
    comment         : stream2
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
  Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (High), yuvj420p(pc, bt709, progressive), 640x360, 15 fps, 28.58 tbr, 90k tbn
  Stream #0:1: Audio: pcm_alaw, 8000 Hz, mono, s16, 64 kb/s
File 'test.mp4' already exists. Overwrite? [y/N] y
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> h264 (libx264))
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (pcm_alaw (native) -> aac (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[aac @ 0x7fa79fb061c0] Too many bits 8832.000000 > 6144 per frame requested, clamping to max
[libx264 @ 0x7fa79fb04e00] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 BMI2 AVX2
[libx264 @ 0x7fa79fb04e00] profile High, level 2.2, 4:2:0, 8-bit
[libx264 @ 0x7fa79fb04e00] 264 - core 164 r3095 baee400 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2022 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=11 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=2 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
[mp4 @ 0x7fa78f104780] Using non-standard frame rate 2/1
    Last message repeated 1 times
Output #0, mp4, to 'test.mp4':
  Metadata:
    title           : Session streamed by "TP-LINK RTSP Server"
    comment         : stream2
    timecode        : 00:00:00:00
    encoder         : Lavf59.27.100
  Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuvj420p(pc, bt709, progressive), 640x360, q=2-31, 2 fps, 16384 tbn
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc59.37.100 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: N/A
  Stream #0:1: Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 8000 Hz, mono, fltp, 48 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc59.37.100 aac
frame=  186 fps= 28 q=20.0 size=     256kB time=00:01:04.00 bitrate=  32.8kbits/s speed=9.58x

[q] command received. Exiting.

frame=  190 fps= 27 q=-1.0 Lsize=     749kB time=00:01:33.50 bitrate=  65.6kbits/s speed=13.2x
video:708kB audio:35kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.836704%
[libx264 @ 0x7fa79fb04e00] frame I:1     Avg QP:10.13  size: 45352
[libx264 @ 0x7fa79fb04e00] frame P:74    Avg QP:12.27  size:  7161
[libx264 @ 0x7fa79fb04e00] frame B:115   Avg QP:22.28  size:  1294
[libx264 @ 0x7fa79fb04e00] consecutive B-frames: 14.7%  9.5% 12.6% 63.2%
[libx264 @ 0x7fa79fb04e00] mb I  I16..4: 15.0% 14.0% 71.0%
[libx264 @ 0x7fa79fb04e00] mb P  I16..4:  0.6%  1.5%  2.4%  P16..4: 20.4%  4.9%  5.9%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:64.3%
[libx264 @ 0x7fa79fb04e00] mb B  I16..4:  0.0%  0.1%  0.3%  B16..8: 15.9%  2.4%  1.5%  direct: 0.9%  skip:78.9%  L0:45.5% L1:48.6% BI: 5.9%
[libx264 @ 0x7fa79fb04e00] 8x8 transform intra:27.4% inter:64.7%
[libx264 @ 0x7fa79fb04e00] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 81.7% 60.2% 46.5% inter: 9.4% 4.2% 1.5%
[libx264 @ 0x7fa79fb04e00] i16 v,h,dc,p: 44% 10% 19% 27%
[libx264 @ 0x7fa79fb04e00] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 52% 14% 13%  3%  2%  3%  3%  5%  4%
[libx264 @ 0x7fa79fb04e00] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 35% 18% 13%  6%  5%  6%  5%  6%  7%
[libx264 @ 0x7fa79fb04e00] i8c dc,h,v,p: 45% 18% 27%  9%
[libx264 @ 0x7fa79fb04e00] Weighted P-Frames: Y:0.0% UV:0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x7fa79fb04e00] ref P L0: 78.9%  7.6% 11.4%  2.1%
[libx264 @ 0x7fa79fb04e00] ref B L0: 90.8%  8.0%  1.2%
[libx264 @ 0x7fa79fb04e00] ref B L1: 97.0%  3.0%
[libx264 @ 0x7fa79fb04e00] kb/s:60.98
[aac @ 0x7fa79fb061c0] Qavg: 64944.246
```

Comment: When you run the above command in terminal (console), does it work as intended?

Comment: I could not say @ivan_onys It should be since I using a child process there in my code. But Since I need to process the data further I can not test that directly on the terminal. I have added the initial data that the process prints

Comment: @distante add a timecode, then run it in a terminal, tell VLC to stream to file, then load up the video in any video editor and look at the frames. If those are wrong, then this is a purely ffmpeg problem, and none of the JS you're using is relevant. Focus on ruling out where things can go wrong first. And you'll also want to mention which versions of node and ffmpeg you're using here.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I updated my question with my findings using ffmpeg on the terminal and the node and ffmpeg versions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So... the problem was that I was using `-r 2` which ***reads*** 2 frames per second. So, since my feed has something like 15fps it was multiplying it...